# Why Jenkins Search Android SDK Tools In Different Folder?

Tags: android, jenkins, android-sdk-tools

I'm just trying to build a simple android project on Jenkins, and everything about SDK is installed as seen below picture

[image]

But Jenkins failed with this log

```
Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools' (Expected 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\tools')
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.1 in C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.1 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 29 in C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 29 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;29.0.1 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.1
     platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
```

I also specified SDK path on Jenkins configuration

[image]

Why Jenkins search the things under sdk/tools/tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a warning; what kills the build is the license not being accepted.

I'd suspect the values in `settings.gradle` to be at fault for this behavior.

Comment: But the problem causes Jenkins searching `sdk\tools\licenses` instead of `sdk\licenses`

Comment: @blackkara just seen that; seems to be a Visual Studio SDK install, based upon the location. running Jenkins as Administrator is generally not a good idea, because scripts can do whatever they want. try building manually with `gradlew.bat -d assembleDebug`. environmental variables can also influence that.

Comment: But i didn't see any relation between Jenkins's wrong search path and answer/comment. Why do i need to run `gradlew.bat -d assembleDebug` manually while `assembleDebug` is already set on Build/Tasks section of Jenkins ?  I have properly installed SDK and Jenkins configuration on build server.

Comment: @blackkara because you won't get any debug output alike that and might just keep guessing what is wrong here. even installing a fresh SDK in a whole other location might be worth an attempt. this questions lacks way too much information to provide a straight answer - there is no `settings.gradle` provided and also the environmental variables are unknown. This doesn't even seem to be default Gradle output, but some hybrid framework on top of it.

Comment: what kind of variables are lacking ? I'm ready to modify question :-) BTW if you meant project's `settings.gradle`, it just has `include ':app'`

Comment: @blackkara well, the SDK/NDK locations are indeed being defined in `local.properties`. Those environmental variables can be set on Windows, when right-clicking `My Computer` > `Properties` > `Advanced System Settings` > `Environment Variables...` (where one can define them per user and also system-wide). eg. when running Jenkins as user Jenkins (as it usually is meant to be), one can set whole other variables for that user alike this (besides the variables one can set in the GUI). Only know that it picks them up, so they might possibly interfere.

Comment: 1) Set all required env. variables related to android (platform-tools, tools, tools/bin). 2) Set an ANDROID_HOME as global property on Jenkins
3) Jenkins started searching correct path
4) Thanks